# How to create an ldif from a python dict

Tags: python, ldap

i want to write a lot of data to an LDAP-Server (preferably using an ldif), but i also want that every insert/modify/delete in the ldif will be rolled back if there is an error. So basically, i need a function, that creates an ldif from a dict and then get the following behaviour.

Lets assume i have an ldif like this:

```
dn: uid=user,cn=testing,dc=foobar #Existing and valid entry so it should work
changeType: modify
replace: sn
sn: Alfred

dn: uid=user2,cn=testing,dc=foobar #Non-existent entry so it should fail
changeType: modify                 #Now because this fails, the first change
replace: sn                        #should be rolled back...
sn: Carl
```

So if the second ldif entry fails, i want to rollback the changes that were made previously to only create entries, if the whole ldif is correct.

There seems to be no kind of transactions for ldap which would be exactly what i am looking for. Till now i only found the deprecated ldif parser for python...but since its deprecated i do not want to use it anymore. So if any of you know an alternative please tell me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP client should consider using LDAP transactions as specified in [RFC5805](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5805).

Comment: but this is also experimental...isn't there any built-in method or a clean workaround?

Comment: Check with your server administrators to determine whether transaction support is available in the server. Modern, professional-quality servers support transactions as defined in 5805. An alternative is available if your using the UnboundID Directory Server: The MultiUpdateExtendedRequest in which the LDAP client can submit multiple updates in a single extended request in an atomic fashion.